# Preventing a section of html from referring to other tags / elements on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a php webpage that includes some graphical dials created with css and javascript (and an ajax call).  Each dial is added to the webpage using:

```
$_SESSION['info'] = dial1 Specific info. 
include 'dial.php'; 

$_SESSION['info'] = dial2 Specific info.  
include 'dial.php';
```

Inside dial.php, there is a section that analyzes the SESSION variable to adjust an arm on the dial, and creates the dials circular shape with css.  The problem I'm trying to solve is the second dial is a copy of the first dial, and not distinct.

How can I make the above code force each "include 'dial.php'" to operate independently from each other and not interact with each other (since the variables, function names, and css names are the same for each dial).

Best Regards

Comment: use a different id for each dial

Comment: $_SESSION['info'] is a variable in session it can't hold 2 different object!

Comment: So the $_SESSION['info'] should actually be the same for both.  To go into more detail, 
$_SESSION['info'] is an ID number.
dial.php will take that ID number and read a .txt document with information which is comma separated  A separate php script is called to extract a specific value in the .txt document.  dial1 extracts a different value than dial2.  In the future, I want different ID values, so thank you for the array suggestion.
Like other programming languages, is there a way to make variables local using html and/or php?  Can I put each "include statement" in a tag that will do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can not add two different object into one variable !
make your session variable as an array like below :

```
$_SESSION['info'][1] = dial1 Specific info. 
include 'dial.php'; 

$_SESSION['info'][2] = dial2 Specific info.  
include 'dial.php';
```

for a better answer , put your dial.php code , I'll update my answer

Answer (score 0):

The session variable can hold many types of data but you need to structure the session variable in a different manner to your initial code. If you were to assign an object as the value ( as below ) you can access the right piece of information easily using the object notation shown below.

```
$_SESSION['info']=(object)array(
    'dial_1'    =>  'dial1 Specific info',
    'dial_2'    =>  'dial2 Specific info'
);

then access the individual info by

$info=$_SESSION['info']->dial_1;
```

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using dynamic html tag ids, function names, and variables.  It seems to be working out fine.